# Why is my rabbit losing his whiskers and facial fur?

Tags: health, rabbits, grooming, uk

Since about November 2022 one of my two rabbits (neutered twins ~3.5yo, bonded since birth) has been losing his whiskers and facial fur. The other one is fine.

It started with him losing his eyebrow whiskers, leaving little dotted patches that might be the roots of where the hair should be (bottom picture). Then the ones around his mouth and below his eyes. Then the fur itself started to come off.

I took him to the vet. He had an inspection by a generalist and then by someone more experienced with rabbits. We tried a mite treatment (spot application on neck) and then they did blood tests. The blood test came back with what the vet described as "slightly low" thyroid but not enough to cause the issue they expect. There are no other signs of ill health that I can see, he seems healthy and energetic and has good appetite.

The issue comes and goes - the fur grows back a bit on the face then disappears again, but there is always some missing nowadays and he hasn't had whiskers in months.

I have tried to think of what it could be an research possible causes, but I think I have eliminated them all:

- Rabbits fighting - I've never seen them fight, and the skin shows no scratch marks. Besides it would be strange for a rabbit to lose all his whiskers that way and have such symmetrical fur loss.
- Skin infection - The vet did not see anything, and it is not causing him irritation, neither has it spread to his brother. It seems to be limited to the face.
- Irritants and allergens - I have moved them to three different locations (indoors in 2 properties and in an outdoor shed)
- Stress - they have a fairly calm life, lots of space to run, a clean living environment, interaction with me several times a day
- Diet - they have fresh hay every day, Excel nuggets, fresh water, and regular bunny-safe veggies

Anyone know what could be the issue? I am worried it's some kind of issue with an internal organ or hormonal regulation system or something.

[image: top of rabbit's head]
[image: side of rabbit's head]
[image: rabbit's eyebrow]

Comment: Do the rabbits groom each other? Or does it groom it's face a lots of times? Over-grooming could be a cause. Also Herpes Virus is a possibility, coming and going, infection can spread from human to rabbit, but do not need to "come out", so the second rabbit could have it, but without symptoms.

Comment: Maybe you can answer my questions, or give an update what is going on (did the vet test for Herpes Virus?)